# Play video on windows 2003

Tags: video, windows-server-2003, mp4

I'm not able to play a video on windows 2003 :-( I installed every well known codec packages on internet without luck.

I'm trying to play it with the divx player.

I have no image and no sound. It plays but wihout showing anything but this message

> This file contains a track in the AAC (advanced audio coding)(code "255") format. You may need to install a directshow decoder for this audio format...

I tried CoreAAC-1.2.0.573 in relation this error msg, but no luck.

Could you tell me which codecs I have to install?

Here are the video details

```
Format                           : MPEG-4
Format profile                   : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                         : mp42
File size                        : 4.03 MiB
Duration                         : 32s 599ms
Overall bit rate                 : 1 037 Kbps
Encoded date                     : UTC 2010-06-03 18:53:36
Tagged date                      : UTC 2010-06-03 18:53:48

Video
ID                               : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : Main@L2.0
Format settings, CABAC           : No
Format settings, ReFrames        : 2 frames
Codec ID                         : avc1
Codec ID/Info                    : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                         : 32s 599ms
Bit rate mode                    : Variable
Bit rate                         : 859 Kbps
Width                            : 320 pixels
Height                           : 240 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 4:3
Frame rate mode                  : Constant
Frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.373
Stream size                      : 3.34 MiB (83%)
Language                         : English
Encoded date                     : UTC 2010-06-03 18:53:36
Tagged date                      : UTC 2010-06-02 17:53:48
Color primaries                  : BT.601-6 525, BT.1358 525, BT.1700 NTSC, SMPTE 170M
Transfer characteristics         : BT.709-5, BT.1361
Matrix coefficients              : BT.601-6 525, BT.1358 525, BT.1700 NTSC, SMPTE 170M

Audio
ID                               : 2
Format                           : AAC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec
Format version                   : Version 4
Format profile                   : LC
Format settings, SBR             : No
Codec ID                         : 40
Duration                         : 31s 904ms
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 104 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
Channel positions                : Front: L R
Sampling rate                    : 44.1 KHz
Stream size                      : 405 KiB (10%)
Language                         : English
Encoded date                     : UTC 2010-06-03 18:53:36
Tagged date                      : UTC 2010-06-02 17:53:48
```

Thanks!

Comment: might help to mention which codecs you installed

Comment: Does the video play on other systems running different OSes?

Answer (score 0):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) might do the trick- since it has its own internal codecs, supporting everything and the kitchen sink. If you need WMP support, CCCP is a good bet, but since you mentioned installing every well known codec package, i assume you tried that ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd need to install system-wide codecs instead of a magic player :-) I'm develeloping an application in c# that need to access the video and it can't because missed codecs. Installed packages: ffdshow, MatroskaPack, DivX, CoreAAC, ac3filter, K-Lite.

Comment: give cccp a shot then - it should let you handle mp4/aac videos i believe

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled Hardware Acceleration? On Windows 2003, this is disabled by default.

Control Panel -> Display -> Advanced -> Troubleshooting

The slider is all the way to the left by default (None), drag it all the way to the right (Full).